# Is there any way to declare variables in SqlDbx 3.47?

Tags: sql, db2, declare

Let's say I want to do something like this, but I don't know how to do it in SqlDbx.

```
DECLARE @COUNT INT;
SET @COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products);
SELECT @COUNT;
```

or it could be something like that

```
DECLARE @A INT;
DECLARE @B INT;
SET @A = 1;
SET @B = 2;

IF @A > @B
BEGIN
   PRINT 'FALSE'
END
```

Can something like that be done in SqlDbx?

Comment: What's your RDBMS? `SqlDbx` is a tool that connect to DB

Comment: DB2? where exactly can i see that? It was already configured. IBM I Access ODBC Driver

Answer (score 0):

For IBM i  (that is,  Db2 for i series) you can use a [dynamic compound statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=routines-dynamic-compound-statement) which allows an anonymous block to declare variables and use those variables in various ways for server-side processing.

Remember that with compound-SQL, everything runs on the Db2-server , not on  your client workstation (i.e. not in SQLDbx) , so you cannot use a print statement because that is not SQL.

If you need to pass parameters into the block, then consider creating a routine (a stored procedure, or a user defined function).  If you need to get result sets , use either a stored procedure or a table function.

Refer to the IBM i knowledge centre for all the details of which SQL statements are allowed in dynamic compound statements. There are many rules and restrictions.